# -not -name does not work with find

Tags: find

I am trying to use find/grep to find some text patterns in my code base.  I want to exclude non-source directories into which my build process duplicates source files:

```
find . -name *.java -not -name *target* -exec grep -l 'someText' {} \; 2>/dev/null
```

Unfortunately, I still get target directories in the result, e.g.:

```
./toplevel/src/com/domain/toplevel/module/SourceFile.java
```

What am I doing wrong and how do I fix it?

Comment: You've got to quote your patterns. `SourceFile.java` doesn't contain `target` AFAICT.

Comment: doesn't work with quotes either

Comment: `*.java` should be `"*.java"` without quotes `-name` interprets your argument as literal expression

Comment: didn't change anything when i tried

Comment: It would if you had any .java files in your current directory.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`-name pattern` matches on the file name. `SourceFile.java` doesn't match `*pattern*`, so it is included. If you want not to descend into directories whose name contains `target`, then you'd need:

```
find . -name '*target*' -prune -o -name '*.java' \
  -exec grep -sl 'someText' {} +
```

(remember to quote patterns, otherwise they can be expanded by the shell).

For several patterns:

```
find . \( -name 'pattern1' -o -name 'pattern2' \) -prune \
  -o -name '*.java' -exec grep -sl 'someText' {} +
```

(AND (`-a`) is implied when not specified between two predicates. `AND` has precedence over `OR` (`-o`), hence the brackets above).

Note that `!` is the portable/standard equivalent of `-not`.

If you want to match on the full path, then you need to use `-path` instead like:

```
find . -name '*.java' ! -path '*target*' -exec grep -sl someText {} +
```

But that's not stopping `find` from descending into `*target*` directories, which is a bit of a waste since `find` won't report any file in there.

Comment: very good.  however, in the real life example, I would like to exclude more patterns than just `target`.  when i tried `find . -name '*target*' -name '*otherPattern*' -prune ...`, it didn't work